How open multi client connection on Sumo using veins_launchd script
I'm working on veins and Sumo and I'd like to know how to modify the veins_launchd script in order to launch a sumo istance with the parameter --num-cliens 2.
I'm referring to this: How to give sumo options with sumo-launchd.py?
and I've tried to use:
./veins_launchd -v -c "sumo-gui --num-clients 2"
but when I press the run button on omnett++, it appears this error:
Error
I also tried to launch the sumo just with the command:
sumo-gui -c <path to my sumocgf> --num-clients 2
and it seems to work until I run the simulation, where an API version problem appears.
I also don't know hoe to set the setOrder command.
Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

which SUMO version do you use?

1.18. In the end I was able to solve downloading the last version of veins from the github repo.
